# Collection View Cell Circle Loader affecting multiple cells and flickering

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, collectionview

I've got a view that is essentially a book library and I've been trying to add a circular loading animation to the books so that the user can see download progress as they select new books. The problem I'm running into is that the loading animation works fine when it is in the cell at indexPath 0-0, but when it is in any other indexPath the animation will flicker and appear momentarily on other cells.

In this image belowe I am downloading Japanese, but the loader flashes temporarily on Albanian, Armenian, Cebuano, and several other books not captured at the moment of this screenshot. Because Japanese loader is also flickering, the instant that I took the screenshot did not show the Japanese loader at all.

[image: Bug]

After some debugging I've discovered that this is most likely happening because every time the view gets reloaded, the cells get reused and for some reason the order of the cells gets cycled. I've tried overriding the `prepareForReuse` on the custom cell and reseting the settings back to hidden, but I'm still getting the progress ghost for a split second which is causing the flicker.

My code to do the progress indicator is pretty basic. Below is my setup function that creates the progress bar upon the cell initialization

```
func setupProgressCircle(){
        progressCircle = CAShapeLayer();

        let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: bookView.bounds.width / 2, y: bookView.bounds.height / 2);
        let circleRadius : CGFloat = bookView.bounds.width / 2 * 0.5;

        var circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true    );

        progressCircle = CAShapeLayer ();
        progressCircle!.path = circlePath.CGPath;
        progressCircle!.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor;
        progressCircle!.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor;
        progressCircle!.lineWidth = 5;
        progressCircle!.strokeStart = 0;
        progressCircle!.strokeEnd = 0
        overlayView.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle);
    }
```

I call the following function from cellForRowAtIndexPath as the download progresses to increment progress.

```
func setProgress(progress: CGFloat){
    progressCircle?.strokeEnd = progress
}
```

I have since added the following function so that when cells get reused or reordered that the progress will default back to nothing and no indicator.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        if progressCircle != nil{
            progressCircle?.hidden = true
            progressCircle!.strokeEnd = 0
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, nothing I have tried has fixed this issue yet. Currently I'm calling `collectionView.reloadData()` whenever I get a progress update on a book and I'm wondering if that could be a piece of the issue.

I'm open to refactoring, I'm no expert and could very well be approaching the problem wrong. I'm open to suggestions and can elaborate as needed. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

As requested, here is a condensed version of my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LanguageBookCell
    var book = controller.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! BookData

    ...Cell Text/Image/Config...

    if(book.active == false){
        cell.overlayView!.alpha = 0.7
        cell.dlLabel.hidden = false
        cell.dlLabel.text = "Tap to Download"
        cell.progressCircle.hidden = true
    }else if(book.status == "Loading"){
        cell.progressCircle.hidden = false
        cell.setProgress(percentLoaded)
    }
    ... Other Cell Configs...

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I added relevant info from my cellForRowAtIndexPath @rdelmar

Comment: @Unome
now i facing the same problem tooo with no solution :( 
did you fix this problem ?

Comment: @Rawan The issue stemmed in the fact that reloading the collection view would reorder the cells in question without properly resetting the contents of the cells. I never found an ideal solution, I believe I was able to hack something together, I'll look at my code tonight when I'm off work and post what progress I was able to make.

Comment: @Unome thank you. waiting for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I'm posting the best solution I was able to come up with it.

I was never able to figure out how to force cells to not reorder themselves, regardless of what I tried, everytime `reloadData()` was called, the cells would reorder themselves.

I was however able to stop my cells from flickering when I realized that other properties were also being moved around, such as the titles.

In the end, I figured out I was only recalculating the progress on the cell that changed, so when the cells would migrate around they wouldn't get reset to the correct properties. By always resetting the cell settings to what the default should be within my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I was able to get rid of the flicker.

For those who are having similar problems my best advice would be to double check your logic statements to make sure that there isn't a hole in your code where if cells get reallocated that the settings won't get reset properly. Good Luck to Everyone!